# collabnet plugin in Jenkins Don't take variables

Tags: plugins, jenkins, collabnet, teamforge

I'm trying to use collabnet plugin for file release in Jenkins and was wondering if i can pass the variable for the release field?

When i try to pass the variable it does not take the value and errors out.
Has anyone accomplished this or It's the plugin which does not take variable at all?